# how to get value of the editText in the adapter in android

Tags: android, android-listview, hashmap

I populated my `ListView` using the data from the database that was put in the hasmap. Each line(hashmap) in the `ListView` has `EditText`. My problem is I don't know how to get the value of the `EditText` in the hasmap. [image]

Here is the code for that:

```
selectedFileNames = new String[listSelectedFileNames.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < listSelectedFileNames.size(); i++) {
            selectedFileNames[i] = listSelectedFileNames.get(i);
        }

        selectedFileUri = new String[listSelectedFileUri.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < listSelectedFileUri.size(); i++) {
            selectedFileUri[i] = listSelectedFileUri.get(i);
        }

        String myDate = tv_Date.getText().toString();
        mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listSelectedFileNames.size(); i++) 
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(FILE_NAME, selectedFileNames[i]);
            map.put(DESC,"");
            map.put(UPLOADED_BY, "User");
            map.put(DATE_UPLOADED, myDate);
            map.put(ACTION, "Delete");
            map.put(ID, String.valueOf(i));
            map.put(FILE_URI, selectedFileUri[i]);
            mylist.add(map);
        }

        myCustomAdapterIreport = new CustomArrayAdapterIreport(getApplicationContext(), mylist, R.layout.attribute_selected_ireport_file, 
                                    new String[]{FILE_NAME, DESC, UPLOADED_BY, DATE_UPLOADED, ACTION, ID, FILE_URI}, 
                                    new int[]{R.id.tv_iFile, R.id.txt_iDesc,R.id.tv_iUploadedBy,R.id.tv_iDateUploaded, R.id.tv_iAction, 
                                    R.id.tv_RowId, R.id.tv_iUri}, true);
        lv_AttachedFileData.setAdapter(myCustomAdapterIreport);
```

Here is my xml for my adapter:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/listHeader1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_iFile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"/>

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/txt_iDesc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_ireporttxtbg"
        android:ems="10"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_iUploadedBy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_iDateUploaded"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/> 

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_iAction"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Delete" 
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_iUri"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Uri" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_RowId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help or suggest any example for me to fix this.. Thanks!Below is the code for my custom adapter

```
public CustomArrayAdapterIreport(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, 
            int[] to, boolean chosenValues) {

        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.context = context;
        mData = data;
        this.unfilteredValues = mData;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.arraylistAttach = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.arraylistAttachId = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.chosenValues = chosenValues;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View rowView = null;
        try{
            rowView = inflater.inflate(resource, null, true);
            textViewTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[0]);
            txt_Desc = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(to[1]);
            tv_CreatedBy = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[2]);
            tv_DateCreated= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[3]);
            final TextView tv_Action = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[4]);
            final TextView tv_rowId = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[5]);
            tv_Uri = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(to[6]);

            final String FileKey = from[0];
            String DescKey = from[1];
            String UploadedByKey = from[2];
            String DateUploadKey = from[3];
            String ActionKey = from[4];
            final String idKey = from[5];
            String FileUri = from[6];

            final String FileName = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(FileKey).toString();
            String Desc = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(DescKey).toString();
            String UploadedBy = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(UploadedByKey).toString();
            String DateUpload = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(DateUploadKey).toString();
            String Action = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(ActionKey).toString();
            String AttachId = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(idKey).toString();
            String FileNameUri = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(FileUri).toString();

            textViewTitle.setText(FileName);
            txt_Desc.setText(Desc);
            tv_CreatedBy.setText(UploadedBy);
            tv_DateCreated.setText(DateUpload);
            tv_Action.setText(Action);
            tv_rowId.setText(AttachId);
            tv_Uri.setText(FileNameUri);


                });


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (OutOfMemoryError E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rowView;
    }

        public ArrayList<String> getArrayListConsumer() {
            return this.arraylistAttach;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getArrayListConsumerId() {
            return this.arraylistAttachId;
        }

        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (mFilter == null) {
                mFilter = new SimpleFilter();
            }
                return mFilter;
        }

        public int getCount() {
           return unfilteredValues.size();
        }

        private class SimpleFilter extends Filter {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                String prefixString = null == prefix ? null : prefix.toString().toLowerCase();
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> unfilteredValues;

                if (null != prefixString && prefixString.length() > 0) {
                    synchronized (mData) {
                        unfilteredValues = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) mData.clone();
                    }

                    for (int i = unfilteredValues.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                        HashMap<String, String> h = unfilteredValues.get(i);

                        String str =  (String)h.get(from[0]).toString();
                            if (!str.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefixString)) {
                                unfilteredValues.remove(i);
                            }

                    }

                    //Log.i(Constants.TAG, String.valueOf(unfilteredValues.size()));
                    results.values = unfilteredValues;
                    results.count = unfilteredValues.size();

                } else {
                    synchronized (mData) {
                        results.values = mData;
                        results.count = mData.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
             protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                //noinspection unchecked
                unfilteredValues = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: you can get value of edittext inside your custom adapter class..

Comment: how is that possible?

Comment: if(map.containsKey("key")) { map.get("key") }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing some research I finally solve my problem. What I did is, I get the index of the ListView and get the value of the EditText that can be found on that index. Code below shows how I saved all the values in the HashMap including the value of the EditText.

```
   SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHandler.getWritableDatabase();
   db.beginTransaction();

    int counter = 0;
    for(HashMap<String, String> map : mylist)
        {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            String string = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < lv_AttachedFileData.getCount(); i++)
                {
                    if (i == counter)
                    {
                        View view=lv_AttachedFileData.getChildAt(i);
                        EditText editText=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_iDesc);
                        string = editText.getText().toString();
                        cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_REPORTCODE, ReportCode);
                        cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_FILENAME, map.get(FILE_NAME));
                        cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_DESCRIPTION, string);
                        cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_FILELOCATION, map.get(FILE_URI));
                        cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_CREATEDBY, map.get(UPLOADED_BY));
                        cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_DATECREATED, map.get(DATE_UPLOADED));
                        db.insert(Constants.TABLE_ATTACH, null, cv);
                            }

                        }                   
                        counter++;
                    }

                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                    db.endTransaction();
                    db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to initiate the textView in the java class:

```
EditText txt_iDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_iDesc);
```

then set the variable to listen for changes in text and change the variable when a text change is detected

```
txt_iDesc.setOnTextChangedListener(this);
```

Im new to this as well but hopefully this helps